# How to show on QML (Qt) from SQLite BLOB data as image?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml, blob

My code is like below.

Name - as TEXT field,

Photo - as BLOB data

```
class SqlQueryModel: public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QHash<int,QByteArray> *hash;
public:
    explicit SqlQueryModel(QObject * parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
    {
        hash = new QHash<int,QByteArray>;
        hash->insert(Qt::UserRole,      QByteArray("Name"));
        hash->insert(Qt::UserRole + 1,  QByteArray("Photo"));
    }
    inline RoleNameHash roleNames() const { return *hash; }
};
```

Selecting data

```
view = new QQuickView();
QSqlQueryModel *someSqlModel = new SqlQueryModel(this);
someSqlModel->setQuery("SELECT Name, Photo FROM some_table");
QQmlContext *context = view->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("someSqlModel", someSqlModel);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///MainView.qml"));
view->show();
```

Binding in QML

```
ListView {
    id: someListView
    model: SqlContactModel {}
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: Name
        Image {
            id: Photo
            source: ???
        }
    }
}
```

How to show on QML (Qt) from SQLite BLOB data as image?

Comment: I guess you need [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html)

Answer (score 7):

You have three options:

1. let the model hand out some ID and use that with a `QQuickImageProvider`
2. let the model hand out a `QImage` and write a custom item that can display that
3. let the model hand out the image data as a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

For (2) the simplest solution is a `QQuickPaintedItem` derived class, something like this

```
class QImageItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged)

public:
    explicit QImageItem(QQuickItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent) {}

    QImage image() const { return m_image; }
    void setImage(const QImage &image);

    void paint(QPainter *painter) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    QImage m_image;
};

void QImageItem::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    m_image = image;
    emit imageChanged();
    update();

    setImplicitWidth(m_image.width());
    setImplicitHeight(m_image.height());
}

void QImageItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    if (m_image.isNull()) return;

    painter.drawImage(m_image.scaled(width(), height()));
}
```

Register as usual with `qmlRegisterType<QImageItem>("SomeModuleName", 1, 0, "SomeTypeName")` and in QML `import SomeModuleName 1.0` and use `SomeTypeName` in instead of `Image`, with the `QImage` returned by the model bound to the item's `image` property

Comment: I would see some example for it.

Comment: For which option?

Comment: For every option to compare effects

Comment: I found some example on QQuickImageProvider, but nothing for others.

Comment: the last option has a whole Wikipedia page, I am sure there are tons of other pages on that.
For the second option the easiest way is to go for a `QQuickPaintedItem` derived class with a `QImage` property