# how send value in QImage to image source Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to have a picture taken from the database from class C ++ return to qml

```
        QVariant currentImage = eQuery.value(5).toByteArray();
        QByteArray bytes = currentImage.toByteArray();
        QImage image;
        image.loadFromData(bytes);
```

I had no idea how to do it Please guide me thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html)

Comment: @folibisHi, thanks for your answer, put into a sample code . I'm so confused :(

Comment: From folibis link: "See the Image Provider Example for the complete implementation." http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageprovider-example.html
Does this helps you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show on QML (Qt) from SQLite BLOB data as image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358387/how-to-show-on-qml-qt-from-sqlite-blob-data-as-image)