# Download and Convert Image to Data URI in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, arcgis, esri

I am working on an app built with QML, Qt 5.11.2, and the ESRI ArcGIS AppStudio 3.2 framework. I need to download some jpeg images for offline viewing and then be able to display them in an image element if the user later selects the associated record. My preferred approach is to trigger an XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript, convert the response to a data URI, store it in our SQLite database, and then just assign the data URI to the Image source when needed. Every step of this process works except for the conversion of the XMLHttpRequest response to the data URI. I have the following JS code that does this working in a browser:

```
var url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/christophereby-3733b.appspot.com/o/icon1.png?alt=media';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var response = xhr.responseText;
      var binary = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
      }
      var image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(binary);
      document.getElementById('img').src = image;
    }
  }
}
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
xhr.send();
```

```html
<img src="#" id="img" />
```

However, the Qt implementation of XMLHttpRequest does not support the overrideMimeType method and it seems like the response is encoded differently between the browser and the Qt implementation. For example, the response.charCodeAt(i) method returns 63369 for the first character in a browser and 65533 in Qt. Other JS methods (setting the XHR responseType, using a Blob object, etc) are not supported in Qt 5.11.

Here is the code sample in QML that is not working:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import ArcGIS.AppFramework 1.0

App {
    id: app
    width: 400
    height: 640

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/christophereby-3733b.appspot.com/o/icon1.png?alt=media';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              var response = xhr.responseText;
              var binary = "";
              for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
              }
              var image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Qt.btoa(binary);
              img.source = image;
            }
          }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    Image {
        id: img
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the ArcGIS.AppFramework NetworkRequest QML object to download the image. I can get this to save an image to the filesystem using the following code:

```
NetworkRequest {
    url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/christophereby-3733b.appspot.com/o/icon1.png?alt=media'
    responsePath: "~/ArcGIS/%1".arg('test.jpeg')
    responseType: "blob"
    onReadyStateChanged: {
         if(readyState === NetworkRequest.DONE) {
              console.log(response); //This is undefined
         }
    }
}
```

However, I want to do this in memory and using this approach I am not able to access the response object from the onReadyStateChanged method when I set the responseType to blob. Setting the responseType to text results in the same problems that I had with the XHR request.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358387/how-to-show-on-qml-qt-from-sqlite-blob-data-as-image) but the alternatives to option 3 which I tried above all involve writing C++ code which I do not want to do in order to maintain maximum compatibility with ArcGIS AppStudio. Is there something I am doing wrong in my code above or is there another approach I can take?

Comment: From what I understand you want to save the image as URI, and then where will you show it? Will you use the [Image Item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the Image type

Comment: Why do not you create an application using the Qt XMLHttpRequest that stores the images as base64? already so you will not have problems with encoded.

Comment: You mean do the base64 encoding on the server side of an API call? That's possible but not ideal as it's a second application that has to be deployed and maintained.

Comment: forget about that, what I understand with your update is that you want that code that does not work to work correctly, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if I could somehow get the code above to work correctly that would be amazing.

Comment: I think that only using QML is currently impossible, there is a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53709) reported and a solution is being implemented but I do not think it will be exposed soon. So a solution is to make the download and conversion to base64 with c++ (this possible answer is different from the one proposed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358387/how-to-show-on-qml-qt-from-sqlite-blob-data-as-image) that you indicate since it is not necessary to create an Item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53709) for the XMLHttpRequest overrideMimeType method not being implemented (that eyllanesc's comment links pointed me to) indicated that there was some support for arraybuffers. Based on that and looking at the QQmlXMLHttpRequest source code I was able to get this working. Here is a sample (I had a include my own Base64 encoder as the Qt.btoa one didn't work):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import ArcGIS.AppFramework 1.0

App {
    id: app
    width: 400
    height: 640

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/christophereby-3733b.appspot.com/o/icon1.png?alt=media';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
                    var raw = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.byteLength; i++) {
                        raw += String.fromCharCode(response[i]);
                    }

                    //FROM https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/1.0.1/base64.js
                    function base64Encode (input) {
                        var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
                        var str = String(input);
                        for (
                            // initialize result and counter
                            var block, charCode, idx = 0, map = chars, output = '';
                            str.charAt(idx | 0) || (map = '=', idx % 1);
                            output += map.charAt(63 & block >> 8 - idx % 1 * 8)
                            ) {
                            charCode = str.charCodeAt(idx += 3/4);
                            if (charCode > 0xFF) {
                                throw new Error("Base64 encoding failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.");
                            }
                            block = block << 8 | charCode;
                        }
                        return output;
                    }
                    var image = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Encode(raw);
                    img.source = image;
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    Image {
        id: img
    }
}
```